# Outlook 2007 opens new mail messages behind main window and has to be minimised to use them

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, focus

Outlook 2007, on Windows 7, has just started behaving rather bizarrely. When I reply to an email or click on the "new" button it opens the new email window behind the main Outlook one and won't let me switch to it - Outlook just keeps grabbing focus back every time I try to open the message.

The only way to access the messages is to minimise the main Outlook window.

All the discussions of this I can find point the finger at an add-on called Plaxo, which I don't have. Outlook is connected with MS Communicator and Live Meeting. One would think those would be passably tested.

What can I do to get the focus behaving normally?